# Is there any way to integrate twain scanners (CanoScan LiDE 300 ) with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, hardware, twain

I need to integrate twain scanners with Flutter. The scanner model is CanoScan LiDE 300. I searched everywhere to integrate this device with flutter, but no results found.

Comment: this may help https://pub.dev/packages/quick_scanner